# construct java.sql.Date from year, month and date in integer

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have got the date, month and year in separate integer variables in my servlet. Now i want to make a java.sql.Date from it so that i can set it as parameter of my stored procedure using

```
callableStatement.setDate(arrDate);
```

So how can i make a sql date variable named arrDate?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `Calendar` instance first. And use the same to create an instance of SQL Date.

**Example**:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set( Calendar.YEAR, 2014 );
cal.set( Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY );
cal.set( Calendar.DATE, 24 );
cal.set( Calendar.HOUR, 0 );
cal.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
cal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );

System.out.println( "Cal Date: " + cal.getTime() );

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date( cal.getTimeInMillis() );
System.out.println( "SQL Date: " + sqlDate );
```

**Results**:

```
Cal Date: Mon Feb 24 00:00:00 IST 2014
SQL Date: 2014-02-24
```

Now use the `sqlDate` to set as PreparedStatement's query parameter.

**Example**:

```
pst.setDate( paramNumber, sqlDate );
```

**Refer to**:

- [***Java: java.util.Calendar***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
- [***Java: java.sql.Date( long milliSeconds )***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29)